# How do I iterate over a list in Jasper?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report

I can't seem to find any information out there on this, but basically this is the situation. 
I need to display a set of strings, in this case they are peroids of hours. I'm trying to avoid writing a Java class but I can do that if it's necessary. Basically I want to display something like

```
1-2pm
2-3pm
3-4pm
4-5pm
```

I tried creating a list and a variable and then just doing

```
new ArrayList
```

assigning that to a variable and then doing a

```
$V{my_var}.add("1-2pm")
```

but when I assign that variable to a list it doesn't seem to work. How is this normally handled? I would ideally want a way to simply do this with the expression editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Arrays.asList(T... a)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) method in variable expression.

The example:

```xml
<variable name="listVar" class="java.util.List">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.asList(new String[] {"1-2pm", "2-3pm", "3-4pm", "4-5pm"})]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.asList(new String[] {"1-2pm", "2-3pm", "3-4pm", "4-5pm"})]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

Comment: Since it's not changing, it probably makes sense to do this in a parameter instead.